# tomcat - Performance issues with Java application in prod, minor memory leak or bug in the code? or something else?

Tags: tomcat, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, jvm, appdynamics

We have an issue with our PROD application.. we are seeing random latencies in the transactions(API based, no sessions). The transactions just freezes b/w the processing, no pattern (not pausing at a section of transaction, or a time of a day), although one pattern would be - It is more occurring when we do more transactions. 
We have checked storage, network, db and for other hardware related issues but couldn't find any.

One issue that i could see is - 
GC (Allocation Failure) being written to catalina.out every 2secs - Is this ok? 
or is this an indication that there are lot of objects created

---

Here is our tomcat/JVM and server config
Xmx is set to 4096m, xss set to 256k,connector is bio, http11protocol, maxthreads=150, acceptcount=100, compression=on, compressionminsize=2048
Hardware - 32G memory, 8cpu. cpu spikes or memory usage are all normal during 
these events. Even GC collection time per min looks normal too. 
We use appdynamics and that doesn't point to any issues as well.
we use log4j that writes the logging which points to this latency.

### tomcat 7.0.55, jdk 8_60, linux 6_9, vmware

We use SSL/TLS as well but one way to rule this out is - these latencies are recorded b/w the transactions processing statements which happens after the SSL termination.

what kind of logging should we enable to better understand the delay? 
any other recommendation?

Are they are any PROD ready tools that will show SSL performance? (apparently APPdynamics do not show this)

Does anyone use compression for API based calls when the requests are less than 2kb?

really appreciate you guys for helping out here!

Comment: If you want to see SSL performance you need to instrument the browser. AppDynamics can do this as well. Did you look at thread contention or other issues within the code/JVM?

Comment: Hi, what you describe is a latency spike, it can have a lot of different reasons including JVM configuration, GC, OS tunings, other process on the same server, ... To help you we must have more information : your JVM options, a GC log (1 day GC log in a separate file will be good), is this a VM or not? is transparent huge page configured or not?